# Justify text in a Report

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, reporting-services, justify

In my work we need to generate contract documents that dynamically extract information from the database to personalize client related information.

These documents not only have text, but also they need tables with dynamic rows (ie.: shows some products owned by the client). These tables can be placed in different parts of the document and they can be between paragraphs.

The important thing is that: the texts must be justified (a legal requeriment of my country)

We do these documents with Reporting Services and export them to PDF, but this tool doesn't provide justified text.

i did some googleing and found that there is no way to justify text in Reporting Services.

Is there another way to do this? if not, can you give me some alternative to solve this issue?

We work with ASP.NET in C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can accomplish this with iTextSharp. But I doubt you would want to switch technologies. :/

Comment: i was taken a look at iTextSharp, and i found it very interesting specially the feature that lets you use a template to generate pdf. The problem with this type of solution is that you can't have a dynamic placeholder to include the tables to the template. iTextSharp only allow static fields to be filled in by some query logic. 
Maybe you know another library to solve the problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to export them to Word, where I believe you would have greater control over the justification, then convert the Word document to a PDF.